# Sum up all entries in an ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arraylist, sum

I'm trying to add all elements in my ArrayList but it seems quite a challenge. Tried different methods and functions but none of them worked. Here is my code:

```
    for (Kids ki : GroupOfKids) {

        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date date = new Date();
            String currentDate= dateFormat.format(date);
            Date datum;
            datum = dateFormat.parse(currentDate);


            Date bornDate;
            bornDate= ki.getbornDate();

            int days = daysBetween(bornDate, datum);               
            //code above works fine..from here it's getting confusing

            List<Integer> allKids;
            allKids= new ArrayList<>();
            allKids.add(days);

            int total;
        total = allKids.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    System.out.print(total);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I'm calculating how old are the "Kids" in days. I get an int and put the results in the ArrayList. I'm unable to get one result. I either get for each kid alone how old he/she is or I get both results if there are 2 for example stacked.

Example:

Kid 1 is 1234 days old

Kid 2 is 3422 days old

Result: 12343422

I expect 1234 + 3422 = 4656.

If there are more entries, then the sum of all together.

Can someone tell me where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: **Use** `AllKids` and `total` **from** outside of the for-loop. `AllKids` (case sensitive) will only ever hold one `Integer` value.

Comment: Might help if you didn't have two variables called `allKids`.

Comment: Just a typo while translating it from a foreign language so its easier to understand. If I use it from outside the for loop i can't access the List<Integer> allKids; allKids= new ArrayList<>(); allKids.add(days); where I'm actually adding the days for each kid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you are doing sum in a wrong place.

You should define and initialize your list before the loop and do your summation after the loop ends.

```
List<Integer> allKids;
allKids = new ArrayList<>();

for( ... ) {
    .
    .
    .
    allKids.add(days);
    .
    .
    .
}

int total;
total = allKids.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
System.out.print(total);
```

Comment: Yep! That's it! Thank you a lot. I'm not working with Java so I had troubles understanding where i made a mistake. Thanks dude! :)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see is using the old `java.util.Date` instead of the new `java.time.LocalDate`; then use the `Period` class to determine the number of days (probably could have modified your `daysBetween` if you had posted it). Like,

```
private static int getDaysOld(Date d) {
    return Period.between(d.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(), 
            LocalDate.now()).getDays();
}
```

Then your stream should be used to map each `Kids` to their age and sum; like

```
int total = allKids.stream().mapToInt(k -> getDaysOld(k.getbornDate())).sum();
```